# How do I scale an entire webpage for tablet screen width on load with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a webpage that is 1800x1200px in dimension (made for desktop PCs). On tablets the page isn't viewed entirely, part of it spans over the right viewport. What I want to achieve is that the webpage displays correctly on tablets using a smaller zoomfactor. I'm absolute beginner with javascript, can anyone explain the js code to me to do that?

Comment: You should use media queries in css, not javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this in the `<head>` section

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Also you might have to use CSS media queries. If you are not familiar with that, Its better to learn it first.

For the time being, use the below media queries in your css

```
@media (min-width:320px)  { /* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */ }
@media (min-width:481px)  { /* portrait e-readers (Nook/Kindle), smaller tablets @ 600 or @ 640 wide. */ }
@media (min-width:641px)  { /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, landscape e-readers, landscape 800x480 or 854x480 phones */ }
@media (min-width:961px)  { /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */ }
@media (min-width:1025px) { /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ }
@media (min-width:1281px) { /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ }
```

Sample usage

```
/* Use a media query to add a breakpoint at 768px: */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px and max-width: 1023px) {
  .main{
    width: 80%; /* The main class's width is 80% , when the viewport is gretaer than 768px or smaller than 1023px which is ideal for tablets (not big tablets) */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries for achieving this behaviour, example as follows -

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

This will apply a background color when the screen size will be 600px or smaller.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer i can give right now is to use css `zoom`

```css
body{zoom:30%}
body:after{content:"lol"}
```